# Order in boxplots ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I found several questions regarding this issue but couldn't find the answer.

I have a data frame called my.pi1:

```
ID_label  value.PI  SortWestEast
Ind4  2       1
Ind4  5       1
Ind6  7       2
Ind6  9       2
```

I want to make a boxplot with ID in X, value.PI in Y and that the X axis is ordered following the SortWestEast.

I ordered my data frame before plotting:

```
my.pi1 <- arrange(my.pi1, SortWestEast)
```

But when doing the plot, it's not well ordered:

```
Plot_Pi1  <- ggplot(my.pi1) + aes(x = ID_label, y = value.PI) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA, lwd=0.2, alpha=0)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Note that I don't want to use "fill=factor(ID_label, levels=c(...)) because I have hundreds of ID_labels!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use forcats. You can use with mutate before calling ggplot.

`mutate(ID_label = fct_reorder(ID_label, value.PI, sum))`

Other methods and more can be found [here](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/267-reorder-a-variable-in-ggplot2.html).